# Could felines live without meat?

Tags: nutrition, diet, feline, vegetarianism

Algae are a source of taurine and mushrooms are a source of vitamin D3. Both also contain high protein. So, it seems possible to feed a cat or other felines without any meat. Are there any concerns to have them live with this kind of diet?

Comment: This seems to have already been answered on [pets stack exchange](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/can-i-feed-my-cat-a-vegetarian-or-vegan-diet)

Comment: @RoryM Already read and they always mention the same things I have search all these times, VitaminD3 and Taurine, which I present here that it could possible because there are these things contain both. And while mushroom is not meat It is very meatlike with taste of glutamic so cat love them too

Comment: Related: [Is there benefit to feeding my cats food that incorporates fruits and vegetables?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1885/is-there-benefit-to-feeding-my-cats-cat-food-that-incorporates-fruits-and-vegeta)

Comment: @Zaralynda sorry but not so related. Because fungi and algae aren't fruit and veggie in terms of nutrition. They are composed of animal part more than plant. High protein than sugar. And no one mention about them

Comment: No, fungi are ***not*** "animal more than plant". They are a third group, independently evolved and different from either. The fact that they share a flavor component with meat that plants generally don't (umami) does noit say anything at all about their nutritional content, and the latter is what matters. (I haven't tried offering my cats mushrooms. They might appreciate the umami flavor. Then again, one of them loves fish but is apparently allergic to it, so they don't always know what is and isn't good for them.

Comment: @keshlam I have already read about nutrition fact of mushroom so I selectively use the sentence "composed of animal part more than plant. High protein than sugar" (except some species contain high sugar). And I never said that fungi is animal